# The infinite union of open disks

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

"Consider the following open disks:

$D(0,1) = \{z ∈ \mathbb{C} : \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$

$D(0,p) = \{z ∈ \mathbb{C} : \lvert z\rvert < p\}$ with $0<p<1$

i) Prove that $D(0,1) = \cup_{0<p<1}D(0,p)$

ii) Is it possible to find $0<p_1<...<p_i<...<p_n<1$, such that $D(0,1) = \cup_{i=1}^{n}D(0,p_i)$?

Justify your answer."

Right now I'm struggling to figure out where to start a rigorous proof. It just seems obvious, but I'm not sure how to put it into words

Comment: Have you tried anything? Part a) asks you to show that two sets are equal. Do you know a proof strategy that can work when that is the kind of question you have? For b), do you think the answer is yes or no? You say “It just seems obvious.” Since b) is a yes-or-no question, what does it mean to say it seems obvious?

Comment: What you mean by tried anything? I have an idea, but no idea how to prove it rigorously. My idea for a) Since both are open sets about 0 with a supremum of 1, (trivially) they must the same and for b) If n is finite then, sure they aren't equal, but if n tends to infinity, then they would be.

Comment: @Dinoyak:  you need $p_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, not just $n \to \infty$; see my answer below.  Cheers!

Comment: (i) and (ii) together show that we have an open cover of $D(0,1)$ without a finite subcover, i.e. $D(0,1)$ is not compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ***(i)***, we have

$x \in D(0, 1) \Longleftrightarrow \vert x \vert < 1 \Longleftrightarrow \exists p, \vert x \vert < p < 1$
$\Longleftrightarrow \exists p, x \in D(0, p) \Longleftrightarrow x \in \cup_{0 < p < 1} D(0, p); \tag 1$

as for ***(ii)***, it is false since if $p_n < \vert x \vert < 1$, $x \notin D(0, p_n)$, hence $x \notin D(0, p_i)$ for $1 \le i < n$, since $D(0, p_i) \subset D(0, p_n)$, and thus $x \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^n D(0, p_i)$.

If, on the other hand, $p_i \in (0, 1)$ is a sequence with $p_i \to 1$ as $i \to \infty$, then it is easy to see that

$D(0, 1) = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty D(0, p_i); \tag 2$

the proof is of course very similar to those of items ***(i)*** and ***(ii)*** above.

Answer (score 0):

i).For all $z\in \Bbb C$ we have $$z\in D(0,1)\implies |z|<1\implies |z|<(1+|z|)/2<1\implies$$ $$\implies [\,|z|\in D(0,(1+|z|)/2)\,\land \, 0<(1+|z|)/2<1 \,]\implies$$ $$\implies  \exists p\;(\;0<p<1\land |z|\in D(0,p)\;)$$ $$\implies z\in \cup_{0<p<1}D(0,p)\implies$$ $$\implies \exists p<1\;(\,z\in D(0,p)\,)\implies$$ $$\implies \exists p<1\,(|z|<p)$$ $$ \implies |z|<1\implies z\in D(0,1).$$

Therefore for all $z\in \Bbb C$ we have

$z\in D(0,1)\implies z\in \cup_{0<p<1}D(0,p)\implies z\in D(0,1).$

ii). If $0<p_1<...<p_n<1$ then $|(1+p_n)/2|=(1+p_n)/2<1$ so $$(1+p_n)/2\in D(0,1) \setminus \cup_{j=1}^n D(0,p_j)$$ because $|(1+p_n)/2|=(1+p_n)/2>p_n\geq p_j$ for each $j$ from $1$ to $n.$

Comment: For ii) we could also say that $p_n\in D(0,1)\setminus \cup_{j=1}^n D(0,p_j).$